# Selenium login script

Tags: python, loops, selenium, iteration, login-script

I'm attempting to write a script that will take a text file of credentials(delimited by ':') and login to a website and display when the login attempt was successful or not, then sign out, in a loop until the end of the text file is reached.

I have most of the code working, aside from the portion that reads from the text file and inserts the username/password strings where they are supposed to go (lines 13-18) and the overall loop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from itertools import cycle
import time
#importing various modules for added functionality



browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.example.com")
#creates browser object  
#b.o. makes GET request to specified site

username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")   
##looks for the html element "email" on above site
##looks for the html element "password" on above site



with open('creds.txt', 'r') as fp:
        credentials = [x.strip().split(':') for x in fp.readlines()]

for uname,pwd in cycle(credentials):

    username.send_keys(username from creds.txt file)
    password.send_keys(password from creds.txt file) 
    ##send username from file as email element value
    ##send password from file as password element value

    login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_id("signInBtn")
    login_attempt.click()
    ##looks for the html element "signInBtn" on above site
    ##simulates clicking of button

    time.sleep(2)

    title = browser.title
    print title
    #find the title of the html page and print it

    welcome = browser.find_element_by_id("specific_element")
    welcome_text = welcome.text.split()[1]
    read_welcome = welcome_text.encode('utf-8')
    #after successful login, look for element that is only present after successful login
    #Welcome, <name>; only want the name here
    #name was displaying in unicode for some reason, this converts the name as a normal string

    if 'specific_string' in title:
    #if string found in title variable
        print "Login Sucessful for %r " % read_welcome
        #"Login Successful for <name>"
        browser.get("http://www.link_to_sign_out")
        #simulate signing out


    elif 'specific_string' not in title:
    #if string not found in title variable
        print "Sign In failed.."  
        #"Sign In failed.."
        browser.get("http://www.link_to_sign_out")
        ##simulate signing out

    else:
        print 'Error..'
        #If neither condition is met "Error" is printed

    browser.close()
```

I've read two other SO entries that asked similar questions, but the answers didn't seem to fit exactly what I'm trying to do. 
[Python Login Script; multiple passwords per account](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817354/python-login-script-multiple-passwords-per-account)
[Python Login Script; Usernames and Passwords in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560739/python-login-script-usernames-and-passwords-in-a-separate-file?noredirect=1#comment32564327_21560739)

Similar to the user that asked those questions, my script works with hard coded credentials. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you exclude `login_attempt` from loop? You just input credentials many times without login to site

Comment: I edited the code to include the loop attempt, along with the rest of the actions inside of the for loop. This still only tests the first uname:pwd from the text file. How do I submit each additional uname:pwd combo?

Comment: try to include your `for` loop into `with` block

Comment: Thanks! I did what you suggested and played around a bit more and got it to work :)