# Why does my sub-routine continue to carry out all of my if statements after I've called another sub-routine

Tags: python, if-statement, subroutine

My logins() sub routine will continue to carry out both the else and elif parts after it has found a login and has verified the password. I cant seem to understand why its doing this but is really halting my progress. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SjO.png)

```
def login ():
Username_Input = input("Please enter your username : ")
logins = open("logins.csv","r")
List_Information = list(csv.reader(logins))
for x in List_Information:# loops through all lists
    if x[0] != Username_Input :
        print("Username not found please register ")
        register () 
    else:
        Password_Input = input("Username found please enter your password : ")
        for x in List_Information:
            if x[1] == Password_Input :
                print("Loged in lets get this game going. ")
                game()
            else :
                print("nope sorry password not found lets go back to the menu : ")
                Menu()
```

Comment: Please, paste your program output to the question. No images of text.

Comment: This thread might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560739/python-login-script-usernames-and-passwords-in-a-separate-file

Comment: *"will continue to carry ou"*: You do it **all** inside the `for ...` loop. You have to use `break` if you want to end the loop. Read [break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it has found the correct password it will continue going through the List_information after calling game(). The call to game() would not stop the looping and thus it finds the next user from the List_information and say that the password was wrong.

You should be finding the correct entry from the List_information (based on the username) and the check the password against that entry. Now you are basically only comparing the first element in the List_information.

Something like this:

```
user = None
for x in List_information:
  if x[0] == Username_input:
    user = x
if user == None:
  print("Username not found please register ")
  register ()
else:
  Password_Input = input("Username found please enter your password : ")
  if user[1] == Password_input:
    game()
  else:
    Menu()
```