# python username/password program that uses ext. files. works until there is more than one user

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

All works fine when just one user has written in a username and password but as soon as another username and password has been written into the external files the read section can't operate properly.

Contains two external files on for usernames and one for passwords

username write

```
    #username
username = open('username.txt','a')
username1 = input ('What do you want your username to be? ')
username.write (username1 + '\n')
username.close()
```

password write

```
    #password
password = open('password.txt','a')
password1 = input ('What do you want your password to be? ')
password.write (password1 + '\n')
password.close
input('')
```

username read

```
username = open('username.txt','r')
username1 = username.readline()
username2 = input ('Player 1 enter your username. ')
username2 = username2 + '\n'
while username2 != username1:
    username2 = input ('Your username does not match, please try again ')
username.close()
```

password read

```
password = open('password.txt','r')
password1 = password.readline()
password2 = input ('Player 1 enter your password. ')
password2 = password2 + '\n'
while password2 != password1:
    password2 = input ('Your password does not match, please try again ')
password.close()
```

Can anyone help?

It's a string output

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please think how you would explain this problem to a coworker who had volunteered to help you - you would provide more information than this. The community needs to understand exactly what output you are expecting from your code, and what you are getting in practice. Thanks.

Comment: This looks very similar to a question from a few weeks ago with the same oddball division of user names and passwords in separate files. Keeping the user name and password in the same file with a special delimiter is probably what you end up realizing you want (maybe look into JSON or pickles or something to handle serialization of strings in disk files for you).

Comment: Thank you for the insight do I need to add anything else or is it good now?     - to MandyShaw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Login Script; Usernames and Passwords in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560739/python-login-script-usernames-and-passwords-in-a-separate-file)

Comment: Thanks that may help my problem, I'll look into it.   - to tripleee

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that in the read sections you use only "readline()" method. This method does what its name: reads only one line. Therefore, you can't access the second line (even if it exists).

Moreover, in this fashion, when you each time open a file - you start it from scratch. In fact, you don't append anything but simply create a new file each time and put your data there - so each time you have only one line.

So your main problem is lack of parsing the whole file. Hope it helps you find the solution.